# f:param and f:viewparam setter not called

Tags: jsf, el, viewparams

I have a xhtml page where i have an outputlink with f:param

`<h:outputLink value="#{formService.getStartFormData(v_process.id).formKey}">
                    Start
                    <f:param name="processDefinitionKey" value="#{v_process.key}"></f:param>
                </h:outputLink>`

in the target page , i have view param

```
f:metadata>
        <!-- bind the key of the process to be started -->
        <f:viewParam name="processDefinitionKey" value="#{processList.processDefinitionKey}"/> 

    </f:metadata>
```

my bean is

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ProcessList{

private String processDefinitionKey ; 

@Inject
private RepositoryService repositoryService;

@Produces
@Named("processDefinitionList")
public List<ProcessDefinition> getProcessDefinitionList() {
return repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery()
        .list();
}

public void setProcessDefinitionKey(String processDefinitionKey1) {
  System.out.println("setProcessDefinitionKey "+processDefinitionKey1);
this.processDefinitionKey = processDefinitionKey1;
}

public String getProcessDefinitionKey() {
  System.out.println("getProcessDefinitionKey______ "+processDefinitionKey);
return processDefinitionKey;
}


}
```

processDefinitionKey is null , the setter is not called , what's wrong ?
are there any configurations in web.xml or faces-config.xml to add?
in the same project i work with primefaces and spring security

this is the whole page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <!-- bind the key of the process to be started -->
        <f:viewParam name="processDefinitionKey" value="#{processList.processDefinitionKey}" />
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
```

Thank you for replying , please this did not work

Comment: I think you are missing the setter for this method: `public List<ProcessDefinition> getProcessDefinitionList()`. Can you try that?

Comment: @cacho: Why exactly would a setter for that property be necessary in this particular case?

Comment: @BalusC: Because I think that code represents a JSF Java Bean, consequently, it needs to have a getter/setter for each property, am I right?

Comment: @cacho: No. Setters are not necessary for output-only values. Besides, if the missing setter was really the cause, you would have gotten a `PropertyNotWritableException`, but this is far from the cause here.

Comment: I have edited my question , a have f:metadata in my page , not in template page .config files or spring security, primefaces or jsf version can have an impact or not? thank you for reply , please help if you have an idea

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the namespaces like [posted already here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17333773/2032279). In my case (glassfish 4.0) and in the case linked, it had to be

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
```

but try

```
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
```

Which worked on Tomcat for me.

If someone has an idea why this is this way, I would be happy to here. Second variant should be the correct one what I [read here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's a JEE7 bug. 
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2868
As a work as a workaround I put:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:oldf="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
<oldf:metadata>
    <oldf:viewAction action="#{chooseRoleBean.init()}" />
</oldf:metadata>
```

Comment: Just upgrade JSF impl.

Comment: @BalusC JSF 2.2.1 doesn't seem to be available through `updatetool`.